# where is the ssh root directory of teamcity?

Tags: teamcity, scp

I try to run **SSH Exec** command `scp %teamcity.build.workingDir%ROOT.war 128.12.0.7:/home/my/share/tomcat/webapps/` in Teamcity 8 in order to deploy tomcat webapp.

but, since my build agent is Windows, I got **ssh: Could not resolve hostname C: Name or service not known** error. So, I try to copy ROOT.war file to root directory of where `scp` command is referenced in order to remove any `\` notation.

After that, the command would be `scp ROOT.war 10.0.0.7:/home/my/share/tomcat/webapps/`.

My question is, where is the root directory of scp command referenced in TeamCity (Windows agent)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked the directory by **commandline** `dir` command simply, and it gives `%teamcity.build.workingDir%` result.